# How to display list of child pages with parent in wordpress?

Tags: menus, sub-menu, wp-list-pages

I have following format of sub-pages in WordPress:

```
About Us 
  -Services 
  -Products 
  -Surgery
```

I want to list all sub-pages with parent page like above but the code that I am using

from [wpbeginner site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/) is not working as my requirement. Can somebody tell me that

how to show sub-pages with parent page.

I tried following code in functions.php file:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    } else {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );
    }
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}    
add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );
```

And then use short code **[wpb_childpages]** in widget but it is showing only 
   child page but I want child page with parent page

Comment: What do you mean by not meeting your requirements. Have you tried anything to make this code meet your requirements? Where have you failed?

Comment: @PieterGoosen yes, Arshad! you have to try it. Then find the reason why it's not working to you. Also, provide us what have you try?

Comment: Give your code which you have tried so far.

Comment: I updated my question, please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using only gets the children of a parent page. It first checks to see in which page you are. If you are in a child page it uses the parent ID to print it's children. If you're in a parent page then it just looks for it's children using the post ID. Neither case it prints the actual parent. I edited the code so that it will print the parent. If you're in a child page it will get the parent using get_the_title(), if you're in a parent page then you already have that information in the $post object. See if that works for you.

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() {
    global $post;
    $parent = "";
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
        $parent =  get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    } else {
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

        $parent = $post->post_title;
    }
    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<ul><li>' . $parent . ';
        $string .= '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
        $string .= '</li></ul>';
    }

    return $string;
}    
add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );
```

Alternatively you can also make the parent title a link by using get_permalink().